# Recompiling VIM: apt-get can't find source code?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, clipboard

I'm trying to recompile VIM with clipboard support and I'm attempting to follow this [guide](http://www.moosechips.com/2008/09/ubuntu-rebuild-a-source-package/).

The trouble is that when I do:

```
sudo apt-get source vim
```

I get `E: Unable to find a source package for vim`, although the package name was auto-completed and exists if you type `sudo apt-get source <tab><tab>`

By the way, before I started, I did `sudo apt-get remove vim`.

Any ideas how to proceed?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: You need deb-src entries in your sources.list file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

It will install both gvim and vim with clipboard support.

Comment: Is this still appropriate even I'm using KDE? I never use gnome.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I wish I understood what gnome has to do with it though!

Comment: You could alternatively install the vim-gtk package. vim-gnome and vim-gtk are the two biggest vim packages available and the simplest way to get a proper Vim on Ubuntu. Gnome doesn't really have anything to do with that.

Comment: @Peter Snow: Gvim is using the gtk graphical toolkit, there is no stable vim-qt port as far as I know, that would better suited for KDE.